# how to use scikit-learn-intelex?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Recently whenever I installed a new enviroment, I got below message a lot. Question is after installing this, How do I use this new package? For my existing file, do I need to change all relevant import packages statements?

```
    Windows 64-bit packages of scikit-learn can be accelerated using scikit-learn-intelex.
    More details are available here: https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex

    For example:

        $ conda install scikit-learn-intelex
        $ python -m sklearnex my_application.py
```

I found a webpage about this:

https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn-intelex/

look like everything is the same( like import functions, packages) except adding from sklearnex import patch_sklearn? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. According to the official document, Intel® Extension for Scikit-learn contains drop-in replacement functionality for the stock Scikit-learn package. You can take advantage of the performance optimizations of Intel® Extension for Scikit-learn by **adding just two lines of code before the usual Scikit-learn imports**

Comment: Thanks what are the 2 lines? I only know one line. Thanks

Comment: `from sklearnex import patch_sklearn;
patch_sklearn()`

Answer (score 1):

Everything should indeed be the same but be aware of some limitations regarding the supported algorithms / estimators.
https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex/latest/algorithms.html

Answer (score 0):

Correct,basically the way this would work - for some of sklern calls optimized version would be used instead of stock scikit-learn.

There are also other ways how you can patch https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex/what-is-patching.html#term-patching

For example you can do global patching that would not require changes in python scripts/notebooks

python sklearnex.glob patch_sklearn